# I have puppetlabs-release-pc1-cisco-wrlinux-7.noarch.rpm. Do I need internet to proceed with further installation?

Tags: puppet, redhat

How to Install puppet software in Linux RHEL7? I am trying to install a puppet master. Also please let me know how to create a local repository?

Comment: Please define local repository

Comment: Can I create local repository by following the steps mentioned in the below link : http://www.techbrown.com/how-to-create-local-yum-repository-on-centos-7-rhel-7.shtml   ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

rpm -ivh path-to-rpm/puppetlabs-release-pc1-cisco-wrlinux-7.noarch.rpm

If this installation needs some other dependencies it may fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply RaviTezu ! Will try for sure!

Comment: Thank you RaviTezu! I tried this and it worked. But I am unable to use the command "yum install puttet-server". It shows registration error. Do I need internet to proceed with the installation of Puppet Server and Puppet Agent

Comment: Can you please post the error which you are seeing?
If you can connect to the internet, Yes! It will be very easy to install them.